# Adaptive multi GPU fan control and overclocking software

Tags: temperature, fancontrol, overclocking

Running a quad GTX 1080 system that is at full load 24/7. Back when it was using Windows, I was able to use EVGA PrecisionX to not only set a fan profile, but also configure the cards to automatically throttle themselves at regular intervals to ensure the temperatures never exceeded 75C.

Though I have very little understanding of Linux software, I doubt that the Nvidia X Server tool is capable of even remotely assisting me in this regard. The 'coolbits' settings seem very limited and does not allow for any precision control. nvtools also looks like it hasn't been touched in years, so I'm guessing that's out as well.

What other options are available for this level of fan and clock control?

Answer (score 1):

Look into installing `thermald` and writing yourself a custom `thermal-conf.xml` file. With it, you have ultimate control over the cooling system, including fans, power throttling, RAM throttling, and more.

Search here on askubuntu for `thermald` and you'll find some of my, and others, work with this software.

If you install `thermald`, you can also `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml` for more details and examples.

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow and let you know if I have any follow up questions. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, so my follow up question is...Wut? As a Windows idiot, I have no idea what anything means.

Comment: I don't understand your question/comment.